# Can't get photo to be responsive

Tags: css, html

So, I am trying to get this responsive photo to be the width of the container (which it is) and the height of the browser/viewport (Which it is not). But I can never seem to get the css right. Iv attached a photo to help guys see the issue. It's also can be viewed at Zoeaa.com

Based on my code below, what would do I need to do to achieve this?

```
.containerz section {
color: #000000;
padding: 30px 0;  
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url("https://zoeaa.com/public/admin/social-network- 
lol.jpg");
background-size: cover;
}
.dividerz {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.dividerz h1 {
margin: 10%;
text-align:center;
font-size:48px;
color: #fff;
}

html{
padding: 1rem;
} 

}
p{
color: #fff;
line-height: 1.5;
font-size: 20px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
.dividerz h1{
font-size: 20px;
}
p{
font-size: 14px;
}
}

.btn {
position: absolute;
top: 80%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background-color: #555;
color: white;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 12px 24px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
link: color: red;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
}

a:link {
color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
background-color: black;
}
</style>

<div class="containerz">
<section class="wrapperz">
    <div class="dividerz">
        <div class="bg"></div>
        <h1>We help you connect with new people!</h1>
        <a href="about.zoeea.com" class="btn" role="button">What is Zoeaa? 
 </a>
    </div>
 </section>
 </div>
```

[image: Photo of issue]

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you check this code, I have edited and it worked fine to me and this is my screenshot : http://prntscr.com/l5465t

CSS

```
<style>
.containerz section {
color: #000000;
padding: 30px 0;  
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url("https://zoeaa.com/public/admin/social-network-lol.jpg");
background-size: cover;
}
.dividerz {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.dividerz h1 {
margin: 10%;
text-align:center;
font-size:48px;
color: #fff;
}

body{padding: 0;margin: 0;}
html{
padding:0;
} 

}
p{
color: #fff;
line-height: 1.5;
font-size: 20px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
.dividerz h1{
font-size: 20px;
}
p{
font-size: 14px;
}
}

.btn {
position: absolute;
top: 80%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background-color: #555;
color: white;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 12px 24px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
link: color: red;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
}

a:link {
color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
background-color: black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I am confused with your answer can you clarify?

Comment: hi @Anthnoy, thanks for feedback, could you please let me know is it working to you ?

Answer (score 0):

See the code example below; *the documentation is in the comments*:

You can read about the [viewport units here](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/)

```css
.containerz section {
color: #000000;
padding: 30px 0;  
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url("https://zoeaa.com/public/admin/social-network-lol.jpg");
background-size: cover;
}
.dividerz {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.dividerz h1 {
margin: 10%;
text-align:center;
font-size:48px;
color: #fff;
}

html{
padding: 1rem;
} 

}
p{
color: #fff;
line-height: 1.5;
font-size: 20px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
.dividerz h1{
font-size: 20px;
}
p{
font-size: 14px;
}
}

.btn {
position: absolute;
top: 80%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background-color: #555;
color: white;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 12px 24px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
link: color: red;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
}

a:link {
color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
background-color: black;
}

/* Solution code */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  padding: 0; /* Remove the padding so that the .containerz element can touch edge of viewport*/
}

.containerz section {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Since you have padding set make sure that it taken away from the dimensions of the section element*/
  height: 100vh; /* Set the element to 100 viewport height units so it takes up the viewport height*/
}
```

```html
<div class="containerz">
<section class="wrapperz">
    <div class="dividerz">
        <div class="bg"></div>
        <h1>We help you connect with new people!</h1>
        <a href="about.zoeea.com" class="btn" role="button">What is Zoeaa? 
 </a>
    </div>
 </section>
 </div>
```